# Seeking an example of a nested ANOVA with unequal Ns

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

This is the design:
Independent variables: Gender, Schools
Dependent variable: A cognitive knowledge measure (K)
Null hypothesis: Mean K for men = mean K for women

I am interested in male-female differences and not interested in school differences.

The variances are roughly equal within gender/school.

Complications:

1. The various schools are unequal with respect to level of K
2. The number of women is less than the number of men in all the schools
3. There are unequal Ns in the schools.
4. Within schools, there are unequal numbers of men and women

This seems to be an ANOVA design with nesting of people within schools.

I am seeking an example of such an analysis that I can learn from as I attempt this analysis, preferably in a textbook.  If the situation is just too messy for an ANOVA, please let me know.

Thank you.

Update:
Is this page correct? It seems to say I have a crossed design, not a nested design:
https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/ppc/section2/ppc2331.htm

Comment: I am curious as to why you wish to restrict your analysis to the ANOVA framework.  This could easily be handled as a hierarchical linear model (with individuals nested in schools).

Comment: @GreggH I am familiar with SPSS. Is HLM better?

Comment: In this context, with unbalanced n's, I would say "yes" (though it could be done using AMOS also)